# Generating hex color code from base colors

Tags: c#, .net

I want to generate a hex colour code but the color should be between either different shades of blue or different shades of red.

So something like this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string colour = GetHexColour(100, 0 , 200);
        }

        private static string GetHexColour(double value, double min, double max)
        {
            string[] baseColors = new string[] { "#0000FF", "#FF0000" };

            string colour = string.Empty;

            //if it is >= (min + max) / 2 i.e 100 then very very light blue must be used and must keep increasing so if it is 200 it must be completely blue ie #0000FF

            //if it is < (min + max) / 2 i.e 100 then very very light red must be used and must keep increasing as the value keeps decreasing so if it is 0 then bright red #FF0000 must be used

            return colour;
        }
    }
```

If the value is less than half then shade of red must be used with the darkest shade at min value.

If the value is greater than half then shade of blue must be used with the darkest shade at the max value

How can I generate this?

Comment: I would get me a set of HSL or HSV conversion functions and work from there..

Comment: @Taw: Sorry, what do you mean? Could you please explain with example?